# cmake recursive

Tags: recursion, build, latex, cmake

I am completely stuck with cmake. I am building big directory of
latex documents, so I want to get Makefile system with following 
targets: prepare, build, archive. Main is that they must be recursive:
they present in every directory and run themself in all subdirectories.

But, unfortunally, if I manually say `add_custom_target` cmake complains
about duplicate targets. If I declare them only in root, then they do not 
present in subdirectories. Unfortunately, I cannot reject cmake and start use 
plain Makefiles.

Comment: How is this related to LaTeX?

Comment: Well, because cmake provides nothing for it. Probably, there is better solution for my problem. I had idea to write macroses for autotools, but it is big work.

Answer (score 2):

Try using this:

http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMakeUserUseLATEX